# UIButton Clicked if/else

Tags: swift

can you help me The point is there is a button when I click on it, I want this to happen; target: 30
clicks: 0
round: 0 total: 0
these are data.
When I click the "clicks" and "total" will increase by one;
when "click = 30" the "round" will increase by one and "click = 0",
the total will increase steadily. can you do this to me
language swift 5

Comment: What does that mean  the total will increase steadily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code:

```
var click = 0
var total = 0
var round = 0
@IBAction func didButtonClick(_ sender: Any) {
        total += 1
        if click < 30 {
            click += 1
        } else {
            round += 1
            click = 0
        }
    }
```

Comment: this code is wrong. Because when it reaches 30, the round increases continuously, but it only needs to increase once. and click has to be 0 and count again

Comment: Ohh I got your point your points was not clear in Question. Click is already set to 0. Check now my code

Comment: we took care of most things. When it reaches 30, the "click" becomes 0, but the round only increases once. It should increase in every cycle, thanks for your interest.

Comment: Do You mean that round should increase in every 30 clicks  cycle?

Comment: yes . This is exactly what I want

Comment: @AbdurrahmanAKDAG This is what I have done previously.

Comment: Please check updated code. Its working as expected. I checked in my System.

Comment: I printed it on the console, it says 1 1 1 every turn, it doesn't increase. I guess am I doing something wrong.

Comment: I got your problem. Please declare these variables `var click = 0
var total = 0
var round = 0` outside the Button Action.

Comment: If still it doesn't work please share your code.

Comment: Above code returns: ... [Total: 30, Click: 30, Round: 0],
[Total: 30, Click: 0, Round: 1] ... not sure if the double entry for Total: 30 is correct

Comment: @DanielMarx check my Code Now. Its working fine now...

Comment: I checked it but Total: 30 is added twice so you have Total: 30 when you actually tapped the button 31 times, same for 60 then the offset will be 2. Guess Total should be increased in every cycle not just in the if block

Comment: @Kudos ok you updated it sorry didn't see that. but you can move total+=1 above the if statement

Answer (score 1):

Playground setup:

```
import UIKit

var str = "Hello, playground"

var round: Int = 0
var total: Int = 0
var click: Int = 0
func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton?) {
    total += 1
    let newRound = total % 30 == 0
    round += newRound ? 1 : 0
    click = newRound ? 0 : click + 1
    print("Total: \(total), Click: \(click), Round: \(round)")
}


for _ in 0...100 {
    buttonTapped(nil)
}
```

Output:

```
Total: 1, Click: 1, Round: 0
Total: 2, Click: 2, Round: 0
Total: 3, Click: 3, Round: 0
Total: 4, Click: 4, Round: 0
Total: 5, Click: 5, Round: 0
Total: 6, Click: 6, Round: 0
Total: 7, Click: 7, Round: 0
Total: 8, Click: 8, Round: 0
Total: 9, Click: 9, Round: 0
Total: 10, Click: 10, Round: 0
Total: 11, Click: 11, Round: 0
Total: 12, Click: 12, Round: 0
Total: 13, Click: 13, Round: 0
Total: 14, Click: 14, Round: 0
Total: 15, Click: 15, Round: 0
Total: 16, Click: 16, Round: 0
Total: 17, Click: 17, Round: 0
Total: 18, Click: 18, Round: 0
Total: 19, Click: 19, Round: 0
Total: 20, Click: 20, Round: 0
Total: 21, Click: 21, Round: 0
Total: 22, Click: 22, Round: 0
Total: 23, Click: 23, Round: 0
Total: 24, Click: 24, Round: 0
Total: 25, Click: 25, Round: 0
Total: 26, Click: 26, Round: 0
Total: 27, Click: 27, Round: 0
Total: 28, Click: 28, Round: 0
Total: 29, Click: 29, Round: 0
Total: 30, Click: 0, Round: 1
Total: 31, Click: 1, Round: 1
Total: 32, Click: 2, Round: 1
Total: 33, Click: 3, Round: 1
Total: 34, Click: 4, Round: 1
Total: 35, Click: 5, Round: 1
Total: 36, Click: 6, Round: 1

etc ...
```

Comment: Well done I am upvoting u for good work....

Comment: Well done I am upvoting u for good work.... kindly returned favour

Comment: No... You did good .....